# how to show table content with relation and multiple foreign key

Tags: laravel

I am a beginner in Laravel, I have a tasks table where office_id and status_id fields are foreign keys. The controller and view blade files are the same as below.
in Task.php model:

```php
public function Office(): BelongsTo 
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Office::class); 
}

public function Status(): BelongsTo 
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Status::class); 
}
```

in Office.php model:

```php
public function tasks(): HasMany    
{       
    return $this->hasMany(Task::class, 'secretary_id');                       
}
```

in Status.php model:

```php
public function tasks(): HasMany    
{       
    return $this->hasMany(Task::class, 'Status_id');                       
}
```

in controller TasksController.php:

```
public function index()
{
    $tasks = Task::with('Office', 'Status')->paginate(8);

    return view('taskmanager.tasks.index', compact('tasks'));
}
```

in index.blade.php:

```
<table class="table table-hover">
  <tr>
    <td>id</td>
    <td>caption</td>
    <td>status</td>
    <td>office</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  @foreach($tasks as $item)
    <tr>
      <td>{{ $item->id }}</td>
      <td>{{ $item->Caption }}</td>
      <td>{{ $item->Status_id }}</td>
      <td>{{ $item->Status->Desc }}</td>
      <td>{{ $item->office->caption }}</td>
    </tr>    
  @endforeach
</table>
{!! $tasks->links() !!}
```

How to call the values ​​inside the foreach command؟

Comment: `{{$item->Status->desc}}` maybe? `{{$item->Office->caption}}` maybe? (Not sure why you made the `Office` and `Status` relation ucfirst and your `tasks` relation lowercase - stick to one)

Comment: Is the calling method in the hand controller?